# WP7: Executing a NavigationService.Navigate from a MenuItem click handler from a Context menu on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a context menu in my app and when I handle the MenuItem clicked, I want to navigate to another page. The issue I am having is that the navigation works but I don't see the other page load since the context menu remains open for the length of the click. When I hit back, the context menu closes and then I see the page I navigated to. What's the correct way to handle this? It's almost like I need to tell the ContextMenu to close when I handle the click and then navigate to the page I want.

updated with my handler code:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
    if (menuItem != null)
    {   
        App.appData.URL = menuItem.Header.ToString();
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/BrowserPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));            
    }
}
```

XAML Code:

```
<local:MyListBox x:Name="messageListBox" 
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding ChannelMessages}" 
                                 MaxHeight="480"
                                 >
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                    <toolkit:ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding URLs}">
                                        <toolkit:ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <toolkit:MenuItem Header="{Binding}" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </toolkit:ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="MessageTextbox" Text="{Binding MessageFrom}" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                                        <TextBlock.Foreground>
                                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}"/>
                                        </TextBlock.Foreground>
                                </TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="FromTextBox" Text="{Binding MessageText}" Margin="0,0,0,19" Width="456" FontSize="21.333" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </local:MyListBox>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: could you please post code for the event handler as it currently is?

Comment: updated with requested code snippet!

Comment: So, if I've read this correctly, the problem is that your context menu takes up a large portion of the screen, and remains open when navigating between pages, thus obscuring the page you navigated to, until you explicitly close it. Is this correct?

Comment: kinda yeah. It basically stays open preventing the new page from coming into view. I can't actually see the new page rendered until I dismiss the context menu. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Well, that is certainly non-default behaviour. The default order of events should be [Select Context Menu Item]->[Context Menu minimises]->[Animate out of old page]->[Animate into new page]. So, I would suggest some property or behaviour is overwriting this default behaviour. Posting the XAML might help with diagnosis.

Comment: You need to post the code where you defined the ContextMenu (probably some XAML of yours). I don't think your approach here is right.

Comment: Posted my XAML code. It's a listbox (I subclassed it and overriden the OnItemsChanged to have it always scrolltoView the last Item) with a ContextMenu attached to every item via a DataTemplate. Pretty simple.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it in a very hacky way. Let me first illustrate that this actually is a problem. Check this article out: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-ContextMenu-in-depth--Part1-key-concepts-and-API , you'll notice in the screenshots that the context menu stays open underneath the MessageBox that gets launched from the menuItemClick event. It doesn't go away. This is my issue. So what I did was put an event handler for isOpening on the context menu so that I can easily get a reference to the ContextMenu. Then in the MenuItem clicked handler, I called isOpen = false on that ref.

Answer (score 0):

Does setting `e.Handled = true` within your click event handler help?